# Are there any PyQt sqlite browser/manager?

Tags: sqlite, pyqt

I'm developing a program using PyQt4 and sqlite,

I want to include a small sqlite browser/editor/manager, just like sqliteman or sqlitebrowser,

are there any one written by pyqt?

Comment: if there are none, I will create my version....

Comment: Did you finally manage to find any good solution? I was looking for something similar to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the C++ SQL Browser demo shipped with Qt, and perhaps port it to Python.

Answer (score 1):

The [Eric Python IDE](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/) has a sql browser. It is open source and it's been written by pyqt.